# spring context - how to load properties file specified as system property in a batch file

Tags: spring, properties, system

I have a batch file which will set a system property with config.properties and execute a jar file. Spring context file inside the jar needs to load this property file to set the jdbc connection settings related bean in the context file. But I get file not found error as shown below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load pr
operties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \${config.propertie
s.name} (The system cannot find the file specified)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load pr
operties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \${config.propertie
s.name} (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.p
ostProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invoke
BeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invoke
BeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:599)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at ax.bx.cx.ABCClass.main()
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \${config.properties.name} (The system
 cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection
.java:70)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLCon
nection.java:161)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.ja
va:124)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadPrope
rties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProp
erties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.p
ostProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
```

batch file content:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dconfig.properties.name=../config.properties
java -classpath .;../lib/xyz.jar ax.bx.cx.ABCClass
```

Spring context file within the jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${config.properties.name}"/>

<!-- other beans declared below -->

</beans>
```

Comment: searching a similar problem, I found this resource, which gives a nice overview of managing properties with spring. http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/

Answer (score 4):

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<context:property-placeholder location="file:${config.properties.name}"/>
```

Now since you are using context schema, modify your beans tag as follows -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

//.....

</beans>
```

Comment: I tried it but I get the following exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 i
n XML document from class path resource [xyzContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
 prefix "context" for element "context:property-placeholder" is not bound.
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line

Comment: you need to modify the beans tag to include context schema. answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I already had the reference to context schema and I still have the same issue. Also I am using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext as below.applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I already had the reference to context schema and I still have the same issue and also I tried using the bean tag mentioned in your answer but still the same exception. Other details - I am using Spring 3.0.0.RELEASE version. Also I am using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext as below. ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:xyzContext.xml");

Comment: Try changing it to ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("xyzContext.xml"); You dont have to specify classpath: and I assume xyzContext.xml is not part of any package. If is is, use "package1/package2/xyzContext.xml"